# Losing content in InputStream after performing operation

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, httpurlconnection, fileoutputstream

I am performing data check using an external scan tool. In the process I pass the InputStream into the scan tool. The tool scans the stream and respond back with a boolean value. Using this boolean value I will decide If I would want to save the stream to a file or not. During the process the tool will not reset the inputstream, and it will be left in a EOF-state. Which makes it unusable. And hence the file I am creating will have 0 Bytes.

There is no way I can alter the tool that is doing this. So I would need to find out a way not to affect the InputStream content. But at the same time perform scan and writing of the Input Stream.

Here is my code,

```
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = null;
    try {
        log.info(masterId + " : DOWNLOADING FILE FROM [ " + url + " ]");

        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
        //rbc = Channels.newChannel(httpcon.getInputStream());  -- this was my another approach
        //InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(rbc);
        if (!scanTool.scan(IOUtils.toByteArray(httpcon.getInputStream()))) {
            // exit with fail code
        }
        rbc = Channels.newChannel(httpcon.getInputStream());
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
        return 1;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Handle exception
    }
```

In the above code snippet,

```
        if (!scanTool.scan(IOUtils.toByteArray(httpcon.getInputStream()))) {
            // exit with fail code
        }
```

This is my new insertion. I am calling the scanTool to perform an operation to check a condition, only if it passes then go ahead and write the file. Now while doing this I am losing the content in the inputStream.

What am i missing here. I even tried using BufferedInputSteam. Still not working out. also tried the another approach where I construct new readable byte channel and then construct new InputStream out of it. As shown in the commented code. But no fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have already converted the InputStream to byte[], you can just write out the same byte array after the scan:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(httpcon.getInputStream());
if (!scanTool.scan(bytes)) {
        // exit with fail code
}
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    fos.write(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks DuncG. It worked. But I am still unclear why InputStream is not working. I converted it to byte array. Used the byte array. But got InputStream content lost or pointing to EOF. I am not understanding what happened here.

Comment: In this case getInputStream is returning the same stream, not a fresh invocation repeating the http download. Generally InputStreams can only be consumed once, so as it was fully read to get the byte array the input stream state is now at the end of file position - thus read next byte returns -1.

Comment: There is no way to reset the pointer in InputStream. So the InputStream will be in a state pointing to the EOF. Understood. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the InputStream implementation class. See `InputStream.reset()` or `mark/markSupported`. For example `new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)` is an InputStream that can be re-used like new because as it supports reset(), whereas say FileInputStream does not allow reset - you'd have to open the file again.